# How can I get fadeToggle() to trigger for several DOM elements with a single keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a bit of code for a game that I doing to better learn JS and I have come up against a problem. I am using the jQuery library to perform animations.

**What I am trying to do** (see the //Fade out text comment):

I would like to hide 3 `<p>` tags with unique ids when the player presses the spacebar key. The code I currently have works (sort of) but the snag is that I have to press spacebar once per `<p>` tag I want to remove whereas I would like to do it with a single press. If I use the text() method then the I only need to press spacebar once to remove all the text in the `<p>` tags.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").keypress(
    function(event) {
        if (event.which == 32) {
            if (operator === "+") {
                result = parseInt(firstTerm) + parseInt(secondTerm);
            }
            else if (operator === "-") {
                result = parseInt(firstTerm) - parseInt(secondTerm);
            }
            //reset the player's current expression
            firstTerm = "";
            operator = "";
            secondTerm = "";
            //Fade out the text
            $("p#term1, p#operator, p#term2 ").fadeToggle("slow");
            //$("p#term1, p#operator, p#term2 ").text("");

            //clear the board of any selections
            for (var i = 0; i < tilesSelected.length; i++) {
                $("div#" + tilesSelected[i]).removeClass("tileselected");

            }
            //check to see if the player has scored a point
            if (result === goalNum) {
                alert("You just scored 1 point!");
                score++;
                goalNum = randNumXtoY(1, 30);
                $("div#targetnum").text(goalNum);
            }
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});​
```

The html code is here:

```
            <body>
            <h1>This is my game. Yay!</h1>
            <div id="container">

                <div id="currentnum" class="currentstatus">
                    <p id="term1" class="x"></p>
                    <p id="operator" class="x"></p>
                    <p id="term2" class="x"></p>
                </div>


                <div id="targetnum" class="currentstatus">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.write("<p>" + goalNum +"</p>")
                    </script>
                </div>

            </div>



            </body>
```

Comment: Can you please us provide HTML too?

Comment: Please do not implicitly declare your variables. It makes me cry.

Comment: The variables are declared explicitly elsewhere

Comment: After much messing I figured that I could wrap the <p> tags in a div and then call fadeToggle() on the wrapper div. This seemed to do the trick quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

HTML standard does not allow multiple elements with same IDs.

You may fix the problem by giving your elements same `class` attributes and quering by `class`:

```
$("p.term1, p.operator, p.term2 ").fadeToggle("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider giving all elements that you'd like to respond to the key event the *same* class, and then simply call your function like this:

```
// Apply effect to all elements with class "space-listener"
$('.space-listener').fadeToggle('slow');
```

Cheers